# all_views is not showing a view even I have access to the view

Tags: query, oracle-19c

I'm having the following issue:

This select does not retreive anything:

```
select 1 as exist from all_views 
 where view_name='FND_USER_RESP_GROUPS' and owner='APPS' and rownum=1;
```

[image]

But If I execute this select, the view return data:

```
SELECT count (*) FROM APPS.FND_USER_RESP_GROUPS;
```

[image]

So, I have access to the table with the user.

This behavior only happens in the database version 19c.

Does anyone know why this behavior happens?

Comment: May be it isn't a view?